# Understanding Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain the process for obtaining the answer for question (16), regarding 'c + d = 1'? I don't understand why it is the line passing through v & w.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $z(c) = c v + (1 - c) w = w + c(v - w)$, hence all such linear combinations lie on a line that contains point $w$ and has direction of $v - w$.

Comment: Thank you. I drew a graphical representation of the problem which helped supplement your answer.